# Set http settings on esp32 M5Stack Camera with android App

Tags: java, android, url, esp32

I am currently working on a project where I want to get the images from a JPEG html stream (provided by an M5Stack Camera which includes a esp32 chip) for working with them in OpenCV. Afterwards I want to display the edited images using ImageView. For the start of the project I skip the process with OpenCV and display them directly.
I get the Problems on a Motorola Moto G5 with API 27 (only one tested).

My Problem is that I can not set the settings of the provided stream. I know the URL but several suggestions did not work for me. When i call the URL with a browser all works completely as it should. But the code below throws exceptions which are not helping me further. Besides that i could not connect to the given URL.

The URL which I use for Setting the Resolution to the value 5:
http://192.168.4.1/control?var=framesize&val=5

Here is the most promising, but not really working Code:

```
public void setResolution(final int resolutionI) {
    try {
            URL url = new URL(CAMERA_RESOLUTION + resolutionI);
            URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.connect();
            urlConnection.setDoInput(true);

            BufferedReader in = newBufferedReader(newInputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
            String inputLine;
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null){
                Log.d("ControlCamera", inputLine);
            }
            in.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
}
```

Exceptions:

```
W/System.err: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to /192.168.4.1:80
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:143)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:112)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:184)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:126)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:95)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:281)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:224)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:461)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:127)
W/System.err:     at com.westfalia.trailercommunication.ControlCamera$1.run(ControlCamera.java:100)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Comment: There's probably a typo in code which you didn't provide - `/192.168.4.1:80` is not a valid URL. Otherwise, Java's giving you a really crappy, misleading error message.

Triple check the URL you're using or the code which constructs it; it probably has an extra '/' in it or is otherwise malformed. Also, only software that's talking directly to the same network as the esp32 is on will be able to communicate with it. If you're running this app on a phone that's getting cellular data instead of wifi from the same network, that phone will not be able to talk to the esp32.